# My Ether isn't showing up in Mist

Tags: mist

I had 0.05 ether in my mist wallet and I just sent some more ether totaling 0.18780179 ethereum in total. You can see on Etherscan that the ether is there, but in mist it says that I have 0.00 ether.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x395dc4ff4afbd361a8351adc5cca3d4c4facc22d

I am only 65 blocks behind and I had Ether in my account all day until now. Why is the mist client showing the incorrect amount?

Answer (score 1):

You basically posted the same question twice, so I will post the same answer here:

I've always had these problems when trying to sync with Mist. All the balances of my accounts were always showing as 0, and often Mist would stay at a few hundred blocks behind, and never fully sync.

For me, the problem went away when I updated Mist to version 0.9.1, clicked the **Develop** menu and enabled **Sync with Light client (beta)**

I hope this helps

Comment: were you running `geth` as well ?